# Joining or relating multiple data in one single data using QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, attribute-joins, relationship-class, one-to-many

[image: Sample data below]I do not know how to solve this problem using QGIS. I have tried several ways but it did not work out.

I have a lot of data, I have one coordinate system for each location, for example

1. Alor setar with coordinate (6.200,100.400),
2. batu embun (3.9666,102.3499).

Then for Alor Star there are consist a lot of data based on different year which is for 2012 2011 2010 and other. Then in 2012 2011 and 2010 there also separate data based on month which January February, March, June and other.

How can I solve this data and combine it?

Either use one to many or many to one and how I can relate all the data.

Comment: Please give us more information on how your data is structured and which coordinate system you use.

Comment: i have attached the sample of the data

Comment: The table in your screenshot is what you are trying to create using QGIS?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to accomplish, and what format your data is in?  Is this an attribute table from a shapefile or geopackage, or is it a csv/spreadsheet that you want to import and work with?  If the latter, it's probably easier to fill down before importing into QGIS.

Comment: My data format is in CSV file then I convert them into shapefile. so from that shapefile I want to make the relation based on the attribute data. so how to make the relation between the data like one to many many to one. Is that possible?